# Is it possible to use a web guard inside the api controller in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have developed multi-user authentication in Laravel by using web guard and I made restrictions to the normal controller by adding this line of code

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:agent');
}
```

That means the user must be logged in before accessing this controller's other methods and it works. But when I am going to implement this same logic into the API controller which I have been created by using this command `php artisan make controller:API\UserController --api`. It does not work. So, How can I solve this issue?. Should I use the API guard as well as the web guard to implement this logic?

Comment: is this route in the `web.php` file?

Comment: Yes for the web guard.